# Applying jQuery UI accordion to Backbone.js view rendered

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, accordion

I am trying to apply the jQuery accordion element to the HTML created in a Backbone.js view.

When I try and invoke the accordion after the render it does not take effect e.g.

```
messageListView.render();
$("#messages").accordion();
```

I have to invoke the accordion in a delay for it to take effect:

```
setTimeout(function() { $("#messages").accordion() }, 100);
```

Any insight into why this might be the case. Should I expect all DOM rendering to be completed by the time the render() method on the view is called?

cowper

Comment: Just a question, your `<script>` are inside the `<head>` of your document, right? Have you tried to transfer the jQuery call and your scripts BEFORE the closing `//here// </body>` tag?

Comment: Hi, I do some rearrangement of the HTML in the view using: `$('#messages .message').each(function() {
         $('h3', this).insertBefore($(this));
     });`. Is this done asynchronously? This all takes place in the render() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem ist probably that you try to call `$("#messages").accordion();` before your view is attached to the DOM.

Comment: To clarify this a little. I was binding render to the reset event for the collection. If you're not careful, as I wasn't, it's not always clear when the render will be called and it can cause confusion.